# What is the error in this Python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, object

This one's the program to calculate the frequency in an array. Here I'am getting the error that global name "mod" is not defined. Look at::    tempr=mod(self.a[i])  ,   where I am using it and the function mod has been written in a different function. Please help me in correcting this function.

```
class abc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n=0
        self.a=[]
    def read(self):
        self.n=input()
        for i in range(0,self.n):
            temp=input()
            self.a.append(temp)

    def freq(self):
        max=self.a[0]
        for i in range(0,self.n):
            tempr=mod(self.a[i])
            if tempr>max:
                max=tempr
        tempa=[0]*(2*(max)+1)
        bb=[0]*self.n
        for j in range(0,self.n):
            if(self.a[j]>=0):
                tempa[self.a[j]]=tempa[self.a[j]]+1
            else:
                tempa[max-self.a[j]]=tempa[max-self.a[j]]+1
        for i in range(0,self.n):
            if bb[self.a[i]]==0:
                if self.a[i]>=0:
                    print "%d : %d " % (self.a[i],tempa[self.a[i]]) 
                    bb[self.a[i]]=bb[self.a[i]]+1
                else:
                    print "%d : %d " % (self.a[i],tempa[max-self.a[i]])
                    bb[self.a[i]]=bb[self.a[i]]+1

    def mod(y):
        if y>=0:
            return y
        else:
            return y



k=abc()
k.read()
k.freq()
```

Comment: `mod(y)` always returns `y`.  Doesn't seem very useful to me....

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues in your code:

1. It seems that you want your `mod` to be a static method. Non-static method should always have `self` as a first argument.
2. Even if `mod` is a static method, you need to call it as `abc.mod`.

Two ways to solve it:

1. Make `mod` a global function instead of a method (just indent its definition 4 spaces to the left)

or

2. Make it a static method by prepending it with `@staticmethod` and call it as `abc.mod`:

```py
...
    tempr=abc.mod(self.a[i])
...    

@staticmethod
def mod(y):
    if y>=0:
        return y
    else:
        return y
```

Also note that `mod` should probably return `-y` if `y < 0`